# margin align broken for different resolutions

Tags: css

I am using two images in my site - one at top right and the other at center right.

**Top right image css code**

```
.fbtopbutton{ position: absolute;top: 27px;right: 192px;}
```

**Center Right image css code**

```
#annoying-floater {
  z-index:10;
  position:fixed;
  top:80%; right:-45%;
  width:640px; height:480px;
  margin-left:-320px; margin-top:-240px;
opacity: 0.8; /* css standard */
    filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* internet explorer */
}

#annoying-floater:hover {

opacity: 1.0; /* css standard */
    filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* internet explorer */
}
```

There are two problems:

1. When a screen's resolution gets low, the images are coming into center of the page (on the content)
2. With center right picture, when the mouse hovers under that pic it works like mouse hover on the pic.

Comment: Post your HTML.  "Waiting for solution"... I think what you meant to say was "Thank you Stackoverflow for taking the time to look over my problem and to give me ideas on how to solve it".

Answer (score 0):

Set the width and height of those images in percentage units in your css.